# does telerik RadDatePicker support Hijri calendars

Tags: c#, calendar, telerik

i need to automatically change the RadDatePicker  from normal calendar to Hijri. the idea is that i need to show a hijri calendar if the users's browser language is set to arabic.
i was able to do this when using a normal calendar but not with telerik RadDatePicker.
any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you contact Telerik support directly with your query.

Answer (score -1):

We looked at this in detail and while we are using an older version of the Telerik controls the asp.net rad date picker only supported Gregorian calendars.

If you find a way to support other calendars I would love to know.

Comment: even the new telerik rad date picker supports only the gregorian calendar. we solved this problem by using JQuery calendar and creating a control that inherits from a textbox control, and added JQuery and other features to it...